# Flutter : Turn on GPS service using dart code

Tags: geolocation, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am creating demo project with flutter google maps. All things working fine but issue with GPS service. If GPS service not enable not able to get locations.

Tried
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geo_location_finder#-readme-tab- : Open setting menu.

Is there any way to prompt popup like googleMap app to turn on GPS service ?

Answer (score 0):

You neet to write the native code and call it using methodchannel .

Refer to this link , https://proandroiddev.com/communication-between-flutter-and-native-modules-9b52c6a72dd2

For getting the idea how to call native methods using flutter methodchannels.

In native u need to write 4 line of intent code only .

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions to enable the various location permissions in a cross-platform way.

> A new flutter plugin for checking and requesting permissions on iOs and Android.

Comment: @RaddalSchwartz It's request permission for the application. Not request to the service.